# what does this parse as?

Tags: c, gcc

I just saw this in Bash's source:

```
/* Force gcc to not clobber X on a longjmp().  Old versions of gcc mangle
   this badly. */
#if .......
#  define USE_VAR(x)    ((void) &(x))
.....
```

My question is what does `((void) &(x))` parse to?  It's used in Bash's `main` as following:

```
.....
USE_VAR(argc);
USE_VAR(argv);
USE_VAR(env);
......
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes the address of `x` and then cast it to `void`. The result is - nothing.

But the compiler might believe that when a variable has its address taken, it is "used".